# Can I download Ubuntu desktop on Lubuntu?

Tags: apt, system-installation, lubuntu, 21.10

**Yes! I know I can download with this command**

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

But the downloaded size of the Ubuntu 21.10 ISO is approx 3.4 GB while Lubuntu's ISO is 1.5 approximately GB.

So if I install Lubuntu and then do the following commands

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
# installs Ubuntu desktop environment itself with all apps and configuration
sudo apt remove *lubuntu*
# removes lubuntu packages (optional just as a reference)
sudo apt remove *LXQT*
#removes Lxqt (optional just as a reference)
sudo apt install purge 
sudo apt autoremove --purge *lubuntu*
#purges lubuntu (optional just a reference)
```

Wouldn't the result be Ubuntu itself only? **Even if I don't delete Lubuntu and its apps then also it is fine, right?** What could be problems and what could benefit?

- I don't mind if I have extra apps
- I don't mind anything
- I have 16 GB Ram and a 256 GB external SSD on which I am gonna install it.

Comment: question: if you want ubuntu, why not just download it and install it? You've not really explained why you want to do all this faffing about!

Comment: @24601 Because it is heavy and I don't have so much internet and time to spent !!!

Comment: You won't end up exactly the same result; but I'd just `apt remove lubuntu-desktop` & `apt install ubuntu-desktop`. Lubuntu doesn't come with any OEM, or 3rd party drivers etc so you won't get any of those (they help make the Ubuntu Desktop ISO much larger); and you'll still end up using a large % of the bandwidth the Ubuntu ISO requires (it's compressed; you're missing only the stuff that Lubuntu doesn't provide; OEM kernels, 3rd party graphics drivers etc; though some of those can be added later too - meaning download saved is even less)

Comment: @guiverc is it something else I can use like Xubuntu ?

Comment: If you already have a somewhat similar ISO; why not just download the differences... I have restricted bandwidth quotas; but still update daily ISOs etc using `zsync` which means I download maybe 3-8% of an ISO to get the 1.5-3GB ISO I'm after.

Comment: @guiverc what ?

Comment: If I want to download a Ubuntu 21.10 ISO, I'd pick an ISO that I do have that I consider closest (or if I'm not sure; 2-3 closest) then run a `zsync` to see what % of differences needs to be downloaded, then abort; then try next.. until I know what's closest (re-run & let it download). A really simple example maybe found here https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-20-04-daily-solved/749/9  (in that case it just updates a daily; but I'll start with an *impish* daily to download a *jammy*, and may use another *flavor* if it's newer over a much older identical *flavor* ISO that is much older..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't end up exactly the same result; but I'd just

```
apt purge lubuntu-desktop
apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Lubuntu doesn't come with any OEM kernel options, 3rd party drivers etc so you won't get any of those (*they help make the Ubuntu Desktop ISO much larger*); and you'll still end up using a large % of the bandwidth the Ubuntu ISO requires (*ISOs are compressed; you're missing the stuff that Lubuntu doesn't provide; OEM kernels, 3rd party graphics drivers etc; though some of those can be added later too - meaning download saved is even less*)

I'd consider starting with an existing ISO if you have a like one (even if it's a release or two old; or close release but different flavor) & just download the differences using `zsync`.  This option would be what I'd consider; and regularly use myself (using other *flavors* or prior releases..)

Comment: If it was me; I'd skip the `apt purge` (remove step) & have both desktops installed.  My own install is a Ubuntu install (with `lubuntu-desktop` & `xubuntu-desktop` installed as well).  My ISP used to allow *bandwidth quota free* downloads of Ubuntu ISOs (but not *flavors*) when I download from their mirror; meaning I got in the habit of installing Ubuntu, then adding the desktop/flavor I wanted (*I could do that too quota free post-install by switching to their mirror*..)   I did it to save bandwidth, but now do it as I love multiple DE's install on my system(s).

Comment: Do note:  esp. if you're a newbie; there are costs to have multiple DEs installed; more bandwidth used in upgrades (as more packages are installed), more options in menus, more disk space required etc... but I prefer it; I can decide when I login which DE I'll use for that day/session...

Comment: We're all still learning..

Comment: I think task package is better `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`.

Comment: I also install Ubuntu and then a different desktop. Formerly lxde, in 20.04 I switched to mate. This also prevents arguments on a.u. about your flavor being end of life. I actually had a 18.04 lubuntu I wanted to upgrade, not clean install, but you can't with lubuntu 18.04. So I installed mate on it, uninstalled everything lubuntu- and lx-, and it upgraded just fine. You can do a lot if you are careful and take good notes. And test it on a vm first :)